# Algebraically, how are $-\ln|\csc x + \cot x| +C $ and $\ln| \csc x - \cot x|+C$ equal?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

Algebraically, how are $-\ln|\csc x + \cot x| +C $ and $\ln| \csc x - \cot x|+C$ equal?

I know both of these are the answer to $\int \csc x \space dx$, and I am able to work them out with calculus using the formulas:

$$\int \csc x \space dx$$
$$=\int \csc x {\csc x - \cot x \over \csc x - \cot x} \space dx$$
and:
$$=\int \csc x {\csc x + \cot x \over \csc x + \cot x} \space dx$$

Still, when looking at the results, $-\ln|\csc x + \cot x|+C$ and $\ln| \csc x - \cot x|+C$ , I don't see how these are algebraically equivalent. Perhaps I'm just unaware of some algebra rule (that is likely!). I tried using the Laws of Logs and that doesn't help. Or maybe I'm missing some trig trick.

Comment: These two expressions are indeed equal as described in the answers, but I just want to say that the two methods for integrating can lead to different answers, where the constant is absorbed in $C$. Consider $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. This can lead to $\arcsin{x}+C$ or $-\arccos{x}+C$ depending on the substitution, but $\arcsin x \neq \arccos x$. The constant $\dfrac \pi 2$ was absorbed in constant $C$ because $\arcsin x + \arccos x = \dfrac \pi 2, -1 \le x \le 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\csc^2x-\cot^2x=1$$
Add both terms of ln and use $\ln 1=0$
$$(\ln|\csc x+\cot x|)+(\ln|\csc x-\cot x|)=(\ln|\csc^2x-\cot^2x|)=\ln1=0\\\implies\ln|\csc x+\cot x|=-\ln|\csc x-\cot x|$$

Comment: Please edit ... You're missing an $\ln$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\ln\left|\csc x-\cot x\right|&=\ln\left|\frac1{\sin x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right|\\
&=\ln\left|\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}\right|\\
&=-\ln\left|\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}\right|\\
&=-\ln\left|\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}\cdot\frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x}\right|\\
&=-\ln\left|\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos^2 x}\cdot(1+\cos x)\right|\\
&=-\ln\left|\frac{1}{\sin x}\cdot(1+\cos x)\right|\\
&=-\ln\left|\csc x+\cot x\right|.
\end{align}

Comment: Simple, clear and nice ...and... no blabla ! Thanks :-)

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers (I did up-vote both). Great answers!

Comment: @Matt Thanks. :)